# Wrapping jQuery empty() To Include A Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I needed to write a method to extend the jQuery empty() function to include a callback. Since I didn't want to mess with namespaces, closures, etc, I instead wrote a regular function to wrap empty().

```
var emptyWithCallback = function(node, callback) {
    console.log('Entered emptyWithCallback()');
    if (typeof callback != 'function') {
        return false;
    }
    var doTheCallback = callbackWrapper();
    var doTheEmpty = myEmpty();

    function callbackWrapper() {
        var deferredCallback = $.Deferred();
        callback();
        deferredCallback.resolve();

        return deferredCallback.promise();
    }

    function myEmpty() {
        var deferredEmpty = $.Deferred();
        $(node).empty();
        deferredEmpty.resolve();

        return deferredEmpty.promise();
    }

    doTheCallback.then(doTheEmpty);
}
```

I was attempting to use the $.Deferred() in case the callback contained an ajax call, in order to not execute the .empty() until the callback concluded.

Does this code look like it will work? It seems to work on simple callbacks, such as a single alert() or console.log().

Comment: Can you give an example of how you'd use this? I can't quite see a situation where it'd be super helpful, to be honest.

Comment: Sure. I've got a menu that will trigger content being loaded in a page div. Sometimes that content is a Wizard, which uses the session as a conversation scope. Clicking on a separate menu option that only uses .empty() may not perform cleanup, such as cleaning up the session, custom events, etc.

Answer (score 5):

I can't really see how wrapping `empty()` with a `$.Deferred` object manages to achieve anything; after all `empty()` executes immediately and doesn't need the consumer to wait for a function callback.

Instead think of how you might be using `empty()` with an asynchronous context and then abstract that. For example if it is an AJAX request which you need to empty an element out, then fetch, then display the new data your implementation might look like this:

```
var clearAndThenFetch = function($element, ajaxOptions, callback) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    $element.empty();

    $.ajax($.extend({
        success: function(response) {
            callback && callback(deferred, response) || deferred.resolve();
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
            deferred.reject(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).errors);
        }
    }, ajaxOptions));

    return deferred.promise();
};
```

Otherwise I can't really see the need for abstraction here.

Edit: In regards to Flambino's comment, why do you need the `empty()` deferred at all? Remember that DOM operations are synchronous and so don't need to use promises. With this in mind we can rewrite your function like so:

```
var emptyWithCallback = function(node, callback) {
    console.log('Entered emptyWithCallback()');
    if (typeof callback != 'function') {
        return false;
    }

    var doTheCallback = function() {
        var deferredCallback = $.Deferred();
        callback();
        deferredCallback.resolve();

        return deferredCallback.promise();
    }

    doTheCallback.then(function() {
        $(node).empty();
    });
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but the function actually invokes the callback _before_ it empties the element

Comment: ^ Ah, good spot. See my updated answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you. My concern was that the callback would contain asynchronous code that needed to complete before the empty operation. My main concern was that I was doing the deferred incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

Took me a while to understand the order of things here. I expected the function to empty an element, and *then* invoke the callback. This would be the conventional approach: I kick off some process, and use a callback to let us know when it's done.

In the comments, I asked where this might come in handy, and while I got an example, I'm still not sure it's necessary to create this wrapper for it.

Calling empty is literally just `.empty()`. I would think that that can be done where ever you might need it. For instance, I don't see any huge difference between:

```
// do some things to clean up, and then...
someElement.empty();
```

and

```
emptyWithCallback(someElement, function () {
  // do some things to clean up
});
```

So really, I don't see any great benefits here.

However, there's still code to review:

- As @Ben points out, wrapping DOM operations in promises is rather pointless, since DOM operations are synchronous.
- Moreover, wrapping the callback in a promise is also pointless. Even if the callback is an asynchronous operation, you still call `resolve()` right away.

  If the point is to wait for the callback to finish, then you should do something else. Right now, if the callback starts something asynchronous, you'll just empty the element before the asynchronous operation has finished.

  So right now, your function can be written as

  ```
  var emptyWithCallback = function(node, callback) {
      if(typeof callback !== 'function') return false;
      callback();
      $(node).empty();
  }
  ```

  That's functionally identical to what you're doing now. 3 lines.
- Your check of `callback` is a little worrisome. You more or less fail silently if it isn't. Sure you return `false`, but your function doesn't return `true` in the opposite case; it returns `undefined` which is also false'y.
- Oh, and don't leave `console.log` lines in production code.

So again, I fail to see any real benefit to doing this.